# sed bad flag in substitute command: 'n'

Tags: sed, gnu

When I run this command

```
for file in $sourceDir
do
   sed -i s/$origText/$newText/g $file
done
```

it gives me this error:

```
bad flag in substitute command: 'n'
```

Comment: Do the values of $origText or $newText include any `/` characters?

Comment: unquoted variables everywhere. even if this worked, it looks like a really good way to trash your file(s).   and if `$sourceDir` is supposed to contain a list of filenames, it really should be an array.  Or if it's supposed to be a directory name, iterate over the files in that directory with `for file in "$sourceDir"/*`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `$origText` or `$newText` contains a `/` followed by `n`, but you're using `/` as the delimiter between regex and replacement. You'd need to escape it or use a delimiter that doesn't occur in your variables. But [there are many other characters you'd need to escape](/q/129059).

It would be easier to use `perl` (where some `sed` implementations have borrowed that `-i` non-standard extension from in the first place) that can substitute arbitrary strings more easily.

You may also want to only rewrite the files that do contain the `$origText` in the first place.

Given you're not quoting your variable but still using a Bourne-like `for` loop, I assume you're using the `zsh` shell, then on a GNU system, that should just be:

```
print -rNC1 -- "$sourceDir"/*(N.) |
  xargs -r0 grep -lZFe "$origText" -- |
  L="$origText" R="$newText" xargs -r0 perl -pi -e '
    s/\Q$ENV{L}\E/$ENV{R}/g' --
```

If using another POSIX-like shell, you can replace the first `print` line (assuming `$sourceDir` doesn't start with `-`) with:

```
LC_ALL=C find "${sourceDir%/}/" -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -type f -print0 |
```

Or the first 2 lines with:

```
LC_ALL=C find "${sourceDir%/}/" -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -type f \
  -exec grep -lZFe "$origText" -- |
```